MAUI C# - Find view by name in static method
I'm beginning in MAUI C# (I always used VB.NET) and I try to build a scheduler app.
First, I made a custom control that creates a view(absolute layout with borders and labels)
CustomControl
On border clicked, I want to fire method in the main page to send the ID of the border control
    private void PointerGestureRecognizer_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerEventArgs e)
{
MainPage.lblChange(id);
}

I add my custom control in my main page and the method to get the ID of the selected control
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
   for(i=0;i<10;i++)
  {
   //Add custom crontrol.....
   }
}
 
public static void lblChange(string lab)
{
Border border=(Border) myView.FindByName(lab);
....
}

For me, I need to make the method 'lblChange' static.
In this case, I have an error :
ERROR
Could you help me please ?

What is your workflow that you want to achieve?

You can try the following code:
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public static ScrollView views;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        views = myView;
    }

    public static void lblChange(string lab)
    {
        Border border =(Border)views.FindByName(lab);
        .....
    }

    .......

}

